# mysql exit with LEAVE exits the caller Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In our mysql setup, we have a long running SP (stored proc) which runs for approximately 4 hours ( doing lots of data massaging.). This SP calls different SPs one by one and then they call some other SPs.

```
    SP1 ( main SP)
    -> some long running queries..
    -> calls SP2
       -> SP2 calls SP3
```

SP3 has this code.

```
exitblock:  begin
... some code...

 if .. then
    leave exitblock;
 end if
END;
```

when I call `SP2` directly, which opens a cursor and calls SP3 for each record. SP3 has early exit logic ( with label `exitblock`), and it works as is without any issue.

When I call `SP3`, since it is long running call, it does all the things until it hits first `LEAVE` statement and exits the `SP1`, even though, it should just exit `SP3` and give control back to `SP2`.

Any idea?

Comment: This is wild speculation so please take it with a grain of salt, but does SP1 use the same "exitblock" text as a label?

Comment: that was the first thing I checked, but nope. the same label is not used anywhere else in any SP.